# I've released Bitmap's memory, but it still out of memory

Tags: java, android, bitmap

This is  part of my code,when i use Android Studio' Android Profiler,It shows that when I take the picture, the memory keeps soaring until the thread dies.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri));
                   circleImageView = findViewById(R.id.iv_headIcon);
                   circleImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                   if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
                        bitmap.recycle();
                        bitmap = null;
                   }

               System.gc();

           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
       break;
```

Comment: You are displaying the `Bitmap` in an `ImageView`. The `ImageView` needs the `Bitmap` to display it, so you cannot free that memory until the `ImageView` is gone. You might want to use an image-loading library, such as Glide or Picasso. These will scale the image down to only the resolution needed to fit your `ImageView`. Plus, they will load the image on a background thread; you are presently freezing your UI while the image is decoded.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Let me have a try.